# English -> Logic Understanding Check

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I was just hoping someone with more experience than me could give me work a quick lookover and see if there are any errors?

The question is this:

Domain: All people at a university

S(x): x is a student
F(x): x is a faculty member
A(x,y): x has asked y a question.

1) Some student has not asked any faculty member a question.
$∃x(S(x)\land∀y (F(y) \land \lnot A(x,y))$
Based on the english, this seems to read  correctly, but I often think i'm right and end up wrong.

2) There are at least two students who have asked every faculty member a question.
$∃x∃y((S(x) \land S(y) \land (x \neq y)) \land ∀z(F(z) \land A(x,z) \land A(y,z)))$
X is a student, Y is a student, X is not Y AND for all fac. X and Y have both asked questions.

They look good to me, what do you think?

Comment: Your doing is almost correct. You only need to specify the domain of $y$ and $z$ in the first and second answer respectively.

Comment: Oh, like "for all Y, F(Y) and ..."

Doh! Thanks :)

Comment: @b00nheT I updated my answer, would you consider it correct now?

Comment: Yes.  The update (as of now) is correct.

Comment: Your formulations, with $\land$ after $F(y)$ and after $F(z)$, both imply that everyone in the domain is a faculty member.  To correct this, both of those occurrences of $\land$ should be replaced with $\to$, as in GEdgar's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1) you say
$$
∃x(S(x)\land ∀y (F(y) \land \lnot A(x,y))
$$
But I would say
$$
∃x(S(x)\land ∀y (F(y) \rightarrow \lnot A(x,y)))
$$
or equivalently
$$
∃x(S(x)\land \lnot ∃y (F(y) \land A(x,y)))
$$

Comment: "But I would say" can be misunderstood as an opinion or an aesthetic preference. So I'll emphasize that the OP's version is wrong and your version is right.